# Mac won't recognize available startup disks when remote installing 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to remote install OS X 10.6 from a macbook to a macbookpro with 10.4 currently on it because the disc drive on the MBP is broken.

After following the instruction to get both computers on the same network, I'm at the point where I restart the macbook pro and hold down the 'option' key. Supposedly, an option to choose the installation disk should appear in addition to my hard drive.

Only my hard drive appears.

Can anyone tell me if I'm skipping a step on the macbook which is running the disc or on the macbook pro which is receiving the software.

The macbook pro has an intel chip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking online it appears the router may be the issue.

**Resolution:**
Make sure the firmware on your router is up-to-date.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1340

Comment: If you have a Firewire cable connect it to the MacBook and the MacBook Pro. Put the OS X 10.6 installation disc into the MacBook. Restart your MacBook holding the T key for 20 seconds. Click the "Install Mac OS X" icon. Make sure the MacBook Pro is turned on during this process.

Comment: T : Target Disk Mode (FireWire) – Puts machines with built-in FireWire into target Disk mode so a system attached with a FireWire cable will have that device show up as a hard drive on their system.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We have an airport router, so that shouldn't be the case. We don't have a firewire available either. We'll need to pick one up from work to try that option.